# How to edit a row using angularjs based on text boxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a part of my form:

```
<tr ng-repeat="f in fields"  track by $index" class="clickable" >

       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedEntities[$index].id" ng-true-value="{{f.id}}"/></td> 
      <td>{{f.id}}</td>
      <td>{{f.fieldName}}</td>
      <td>{{f.fieldType.typeName}}</td>
       <td>{{f.relation.entityName}}</td>
      <td>{{f.inputType}}</td>
      <td>{{f.size}}</td>
      <td>{{f.primary}}</td>
      <td>{{f.index}}</td>

      <td><button ng-click="deleteField($index)">delete</button></td> 
       <td><button ng-click="UpdateField($index)">Update</button></td> 

</tr>
```

What should I do in the controller?

Comment: What are you trying to make the checkbox do?

Comment: select the row that i should update

Comment: but the delete and update buttons are on the row so why would you need to select it?

Comment: Yeah you're right i will try without  the checkbox

Comment: my problem is not the checkbox but i don't know how to edit a row  (controller js )

Comment: When you say edit, what editing is being done? I'd expect that there would be text boxes to do the editing

Comment: Yes normally i have text boxes when i whrite the values and i click on save , then the record is added  to the table , so normally when i click edit , i should have the values of the row in the text boxes as i can change them and click on save again

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand what you wanna do but here the way to retrieve all the selected rows :

**view**

```
<tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.selected" value="1"/></td> 
      <td>{{f.id}}</td>
      <td>{{f.fieldName}}</td>
      <td>{{f.fieldType.typeName}}</td>
       <td>{{f.relation.entityName}}</td>
      <td>{{f.inputType}}</td>
      <td>{{f.size}}</td>
      <td>{{f.primary}}</td>
      <td>{{f.index}}</td>

      <td><button ng-click="deleteField($index)">delete</button></td> 
       <td><button ng-click="UpdateField($index)">Update</button></td> 
</tr>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('Ctrl'[function(){

  $scope.getAllSelected = function() {
     var result =[];
     angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
         if (item.selected) {
             result.push(item);
             return;
         }
     });
     return result;
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have an edit mode flag on the field. This would be set by the checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.editMode"/></td>
```

Then in your view you can use ng-show to show/hide a textbox for editing:

```
<td>
  <span ng-show="!f.editMode">{{f.fieldName}}</span>
  <input type="text" ng-model="f.fieldName" ng-show="f.editMode"/>
</td>
```

I also decided to only show the update button if in edit mode:

```
<td><button ng-click="updateField($index)" ng-show="f.editMode">Update</button></td>
```

Then in your controller your delete and update will need to call the backend to perform the relevant action.

```
$scope.deleteField = function (index) {
  var field = $scope.fields[index];
  var url = '/fields/' + field.id;

  $http.delete(url).then(function () {
    $scope.fields.splice(index, 1);
  });
};

$scope.updateField = function (index) {
  var field = $scope.fields[index];
  var url = '/fields/' + field.id;

  $http.put(url, field).then(function () {
    field.editMode = false;
  });
};
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLnq5Ddt3o8OCOwC9RUT?p=preview)

Comment: it works now i can edit but to save the edit i use the   function  that i use to save  a field but it doen't work     $scope.saveEdits=function()
  {
   $scope.field.entity=$scope.currentEntity;
   $http.post("/saveField",$scope.field)
    .success(function(data){
     $scope.fields.push(data);
     console.log($scope.entities);
    });
   
  };

Comment: to get the current field you should use `$scope.fields[index]`

Comment: i think here the button update doesn't  have any importance because when i check the checkbox i have the text boxes to edit wthout clicking on the button edit ?? An other problem is that i have deleteButton and when i add f.editmode in the button checkboxes delete doesn't work .

Comment: The checkbox is to put it in edit mode, the update button was to save the data. Take a look at the delete in my Plunkr

Comment: Yes i just have seen it  , i understand now but for the saveEdits in the controller i use $scope.saveEdits = function() {
      $scope.editmode = false;
      $scope.field= angular.copy($scope.currentrow);    is it wrong?

    };

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. That will set field to a copy of currentrow.

Comment: what i want is when i edit a row i should save what i have edited

Comment: See the updateField function above that performs a put request to the server to update the field

Comment: You would need to implement the correct Api to match on the server in order for it to work. Plunkr is only for client side code

Comment: i am sorry i ask stupid questions but i am new to angularjs  ,how shall i implements the api to match on the controller ?

Comment: That would depend on the tech you are using in the backend. You need to setup server side actions for /fields/[id] put and delete. Put updates the field. Delete will delete the field

Comment: Okay i see do you mean like this  : 
 $scope.deleteField = function(f){
 $http.delete('/fields/' + field.id )
   .success(function(){
     var index = $scope.fields.indexOf(f);
     $scope.fields.splice(index,1);
   });
   
 };